# POSTGRESQL must appear in the GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, case

I want to select a case but I get this error message:

```
ERROR:  column "employee_view.firstname" must appear in the GROUP BY clause 
or be used in an aggregate function
```

sampe data from employee_view table:

```
 e_id  | firstname | lastname  | christmas_bonus 
-------+-----------+-----------+-----------------
 10100 | Mark      | Stevens   |       7500.0000
 10101 | Alex      | Watts     |       8700.0000
 10102 | Hannah    | Burton    |       7800.0000
```

my query:

```
select distinct e_id, firstname, lastname, christmas_bonus, case 
when christmas_bonus < round(avg(christmas_bonus),2) then 'bonus below average' 
else 'bonus above average' end from employee_view group by e_id;
```

desired output:

```
e_id  | firstname | lastname  | christmas_bonus | case 
------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+------
10100 | Mark      | Stevens   |       7500.0000 | bonus below average
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could skip `GROUP BY` part and use windowed `AVG` instead:

```
select e_id, firstname, lastname, christmas_bonus,
   case when christmas_bonus < round((avg(christmas_bonus) OVER()),2) 
        then 'bonus below average' else 'bonus equal or above average' end 
from employee_view
```

Answer (score 0):

For each row of employee_view, you are looking to compare the christmas bonus to the average of all employees.

A simple, efficient, and maybe easier to maintain solution is to compute the overall average in a query, then compare the value with each employee bonus (CROSS JOIN with the employee table).

Hence the average is computed only once, returning just one row of data, and you don’t need to use window function or group by clauses.

```
select 
    e.e_id, 
    e.firstname,
    e.lastname, 
    e.christmas_bonus, 
    case 
        when e.christmas_bonus < a.christmas_bonus then 'bonus below average'
        else 'bonus above average' 
    end 
from 
    employee_view e
    cross join (select avg(christmas_bonus) from employee_view) a
;
```